# I want to send filtered products data to another component in React when radio buttons triggered?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

this is my filter component where i fetch particular products based on the radio value and setting it to my state.

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState(null);

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    axios.get(`/store?limit=4&skip=0&sortBy=price:asc&subcategory=${e.currentTarget.value}`)
    .then(response => {
      setProducts(response.data)
    })
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <Accordion defaultActiveKey='0' style={{ paddingBottom: 16 }}>
        <Card id='CCFilterCard'>
          <Accordion.Toggle id='CCFilterHeader' as={Card.Header} eventKey='0'>
            SUB CATEGORY
          </Accordion.Toggle>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey='0'>
            <Card.Body>
              <label className='radioContainer'>
                <input onChange={handleOnChange} type='radio' value='gaming' id='radioInput' />
                <span className='radiomark'></span>
                Gaming Laptops
              </label>
            </Card.Body>
          </Accordion.Toggle>
       </Card>
     </Accordion>
   </>
```

In this product component iam fetching all products and setting it to my state.

What i need is i want to replace all products with filtered products data to this component.

```
export default class ProductCard extends Component {
  state = {
    loading:true,
    products:null,
    click:4
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('/store?limit=4&skip=0&sortBy=price:asc&category=laptop')
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({loading:true});
      this.setState({products:response.data});
      this.setState({loading:false});
    })
  }
if(this.state.loading){
   return <h1>Loading...</h1>
}

 return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Row>
          {
            this.state.products.map( product => {
              return (
                <Col
                  lg={4}
                  md={4}
                  sm={6}
                  xs={6}
                  style={{ paddingBottom: 24, marginTop: "20px" }}>
                  <NavLink to={'/container/productdetails/' + product._id}>
                    <Card id='stackBottom'/>
                    <Card id='displayCard'>
                      <Col style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                        <motion.div
                          whileHover={{ scale: 1.04 }}
                          whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}>
                          <Image
                            src={require("./laptopImages/legion.png")}
                            style={{ marginTop: "-21px" }}
                            id='productImage'
                          />
                        </motion.div>
                      </Col>
                      <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Text id='productTitle' className='module line-clamp'>
                          {product.productName}
                        </Card.Text>     
                      </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                  </NavLink>
                </Col>
           </Row>
        </React.Fragment>
              )
            })
          }
```

I could really use your help! thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to this is using redux in your project and have a central product state.so when you update product data in filter component it would be automatically updated for the products component also. You can setup redux in your React native project using this link https://hub.packtpub.com/how-get-started-redux-react-native/

and after setting up redux your code would be something like this

```html
const products = useSelector((state) => state.products);
const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    axios.get(`/store?limit=4&skip=0&sortBy=price:asc&subcategory=${e.currentTarget.value}`)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch(setProducts(response.data))
    })
  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <Accordion defaultActiveKey='0' style={{ paddingBottom: 16 }}>
        <Card id='CCFilterCard'>
          <Accordion.Toggle id='CCFilterHeader' as={Card.Header} eventKey='0'>
            SUB CATEGORY
          </Accordion.Toggle>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey='0'>
            <Card.Body>
              <label className='radioContainer'>
                <input onChange={handleOnChange} type='radio' value='gaming' id='radioInput' />
                <span className='radiomark'></span>
                Gaming Laptops
              </label>
            </Card.Body>
          </Accordion.Toggle>
       </Card>
     </Accordion>
   </>
```

and your product component would be something like this

```html
export default class ProductCard extends Component {
  state = {
    loading:true,
    click:4
  }
const products = useSelector((state) => state.products);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('/store?limit=4&skip=0&sortBy=price:asc&category=laptop')
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({loading:true});
      dispatch(setProducts(response.data))
      this.setState({loading:false});
    })
  }
if(this.state.loading){
   return <h1>Loading...</h1>
}

 return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Row>
          {
            this.state.products.map( product => {
              return (
                <Col
                  lg={4}
                  md={4}
                  sm={6}
                  xs={6}
                  style={{ paddingBottom: 24, marginTop: "20px" }}>
                  <NavLink to={'/container/productdetails/' + product._id}>
                    <Card id='stackBottom'/>
                    <Card id='displayCard'>
                      <Col style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                        <motion.div
                          whileHover={{ scale: 1.04 }}
                          whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}>
                          <Image
                            src={require("./laptopImages/legion.png")}
                            style={{ marginTop: "-21px" }}
                            id='productImage'
                          />
                        </motion.div>
                      </Col>
                      <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Text id='productTitle' className='module line-clamp'>
                          {product.productName}
                        </Card.Text>     
                      </Card.Body>
                    </Card>
                  </NavLink>
                </Col>
           </Row>
        </React.Fragment>
              )
            })
          }
```